# Apache Nifi Custom Processor processing only one record from file

Tags: json, apache-nifi, dataflow, processor

I created custom processor to process JSON records from file. Input file as multiple JSON records separated by new line. I am using GetFile, CustomProcessor , PutFile processor. However I am getting only record in output file.
I used the nifi example available on github  https://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/ .

My nifi looks like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THrke.png)

Would like to know how I can make the processor to process multiple records from input file and write finite number of records to output file ?

Comment: Split flow file content by new line, then parse each line as json.

Comment: Thanks this got working with split flow file and custom processor I used merge content to save it back again to file.